# Adding class to select tag

Tags: css, select, dropdown

I'm trying to add a class to a select tag so a drop down menu can inherit some css styling but I can't get the style to apply. Am I formatting the class incorrectly?

Here's my code:

```css
packagesmenu {
    box-shadow: none!important;
    background: transparent!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    padding: 8px 5px!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-left: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    max-width: 100%!important;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom:15px!important;
    text-transform:none!important;
}

packagesmenu:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #ee2b30!important;
border-top: 1px solid #ee2b30!important ;
    border-left: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
}
```

```html
<select style="width:100%;display:block;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;" onchange="window.location.href = this.value" class="packagesmenu" name="packagesmenu" >
<option>Find your location</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspamilton/buy/series">
  Milton
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspamississauga/buy/series">
  Mississauga</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspadanforth/buy/series">
  Danforth
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixenburlington/buy/series">
  Burlington
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/VixenNailsandSpaOakville/buy/series">
  Oakville
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How is this php related? Your title *"Adding class to select tag in php"* only states it in there, nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's not. I'm not too familiar with this type of code. My mistake but I do still need some help with the problem.

Comment: Well, seeing your CSS, both `packagesmenu` are missing dots, since you're using them as classes. Change both `packagesmenu` to `.packagesmenu` and see what happens. If you're relying on ID's then use the pound sign `#packagesmenu` but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: Thank you, it still didn't work for some reason but is the class added correctly in the select line though? <select style="width:100%;display:block;max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;" onchange="window.location.href = this.value" class="packagesmenu" name="packagesmenu" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **CSS**, a `class selector` is a name preceded by a *full stop* `(“.”)` and an `ID selector` is a name preceded by a *hash character* `(“#”).`

So you're class name declaration wrong.

```
.packagesmenu {
    box-shadow: none!important;
    background: transparent!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    padding: 8px 5px!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-left: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA!important;
    max-width: 100%!important;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom:15px!important;
    text-transform:none!important;
}

.packagesmenu:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #ee2b30!important;
    border-top: 1px solid #ee2b30!important ;
    border-left: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee2b30!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your css. Inline css too. Don't use inline styles - this is poor and hard to maintain, someday you find out, right now please, believe me. Don't use `!importand`, it is bad practice, just don't.

To declare in css:

- an element `body` `select` use tag
- a class `.someclass` use dot and class name
- an id `#bigid` use hash and id name

without spaces. But after `:` and `;` always put space. It is allowed without spaces now, but good practice, readability and tradition are strict - spaces!

```css
body{
background: #000;           /* this to see background of select */
}
select{                 /* no inline css */
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #aaa;
}
.packagesmenu {
background: 0;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 0;
outline: none;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 8px 5px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.packagesmenu:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #ee2b30;
border: 1px solid #ee2b30;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="window.location.href = this.value" class="packagesmenu" name="packagesmenu" >
<option>Find your location</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspamilton/buy/series">
  Milton
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspamississauga/buy/series">
  Mississauga</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixennailsandspadanforth/buy/series">
  Danforth
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/vixenburlington/buy/series">
  Burlington
</option>
<option value="https://go.booker.com/location/VixenNailsandSpaOakville/buy/series">
  Oakville
</option>
</select>
```